# Browsers use different font-family names?

Tags: fonts, font-family, opentype, typekit

I have adobe Univers LT Std font purchased and installed on my PC, but there is a problem when I try to use it on the webpage. The font has otf format. I noticed that browsers use different font-family names for this font. FireFox 25.0 seems to use OT Family name (Univers LT Std) as a font-family value, and Chrome 30 uses PS font name (UniversLTStd). So I ended up writing my CSS like this:

```
p { font-family: UniversLTStd, Univers LT Std; }
```

Is there a way to avoid writing multiple family names for a single font to work in different browsers? I've checked the font's attributes with FontLab Studio:

**Basic set of font names:**

- Family name: Univers LT Std 55
- PS font name: UniversLTStd
- Full name: Univers LT Std 55 Roman
- Menu name: Univers LT Std 55
- FOND name: Univers LT Std 55

**OpenType-specific names:**

- OT Family name: Univers LT Std
- OT style name: 55 Roman
- Mac name:  Univers LT Std 55

But didn't find any universal name to use as a font-family.

**UPD**: It is supposed that the user will have the font installed on his PC too. The font's name is received from the server,  and the client uses the font with a received name.

Answer (score 0):

Please be aware, that most people won’t have the fonts you buy and install on your computer also installed on their computer. However, if you have the license to use the font on websites you can generate a stack of fonts with the [Font Squirrel Webfont Generator Tool](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator). These will work in all major browsers and you only have one name that you need to write in your CSS Code.

Comment: I have checked Font Squirrel already. It generates different font files and supposes client to download font from the server. I have a font name received from the server, and the client uses the font with a received name. The client already has a font installed on his PC and there should be no need download it again.

Comment: @phyzalis I am not completely sure whether this helps, but it is recommended to add quotes around names with spaces and for font names [containing numbers](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/fonts.html#propdef-font-family).

Comment: some explanation about the quotes: https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/unquoted-font-family